# Django 1.4 with apache2

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I have problem with Django 1.4 and apache2. I have following code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, SiteProfileNotAvailable
from django.conf import settings

....
*.... so many includes....*
.....

try:
    app_label, model_name = settings.AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE.split('.')
    Profile = models.get_model(app_label, model_name)
except (ImportError, ImproperlyConfigured):
    raise SiteProfileNotAvailable

if not Profile:
    raise SiteProfileNotAvailable
```

It raise SiteProfileNotAvailable error, below if not Profile: statement. This means models.get_model is failed get profile model. Same code in my local test environment works greatly. What can go wrong?

Edit: my AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE is as follows in settings.py file.

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'profile.Profile'
```

Comment: post your AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE string too

Comment: AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'profile.Profile'

Comment: When try to execute above line from shell utility (python manage.py shell). It worked, means it didnt raise SiteProfileNotAvailable error

Comment: When I tried this out, I found that the `Profile = models.get_model...` line was not raising any exceptions, it was simply returning `None` to Profile. In the line `if not Profile` it is evaluating True and raising the error, as `None` is evaluating the same as `False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed profile model to uprofile (now it's like uprofile.uprofile), everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should change your test like this (use a variable already instantiated for testing in the if statement). Your testing for a variable `False` and `None` is evaluating as `False` in that test:

```
model_found = False

try:
    app_label, model_name = settings.AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE.split('.')
    Profile = models.get_model(app_label, model_name)
    model_found = True
except (ImportError, ImproperlyConfigured):
    raise SiteProfileNotAvailable

if not model_found:
    raise SiteProfileNotAvailable
```

Comment: I need to check whether Profile is object or not.